# How do I access ViewData properties in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building my first ASP.Net MVC based app and have a problem accessing the results of a linq to sql query in one of my views.

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var dataContext = new BuffetSuppliersDBDataContext();
        var supplier = from m in dataContext.BO_Suppliers
                        where m.SupplierID == id
                        select m;

        return View(supplier);
    }
```

How can I access the supplier.SupplierName property in my view page, I have seen examples using a foreach loop and casting ViewData.Model to IEnumerable but there is not much point in using a loop as i am only returning one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose the first object then use it as your model.  A strongly-typed view (.e.g., ViewPage<Supplier>) will make it trivial to access the model properties.

```
    var dataContext = new BuffetSuppliersDBDataContext();
    var supplier = (from m in dataContext.BO_Suppliers
                    where m.SupplierID == id
                    select m).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewData.Model = supplier;

    return View();
```

With a view page defined as

```
    public class Details : ViewPage<Supplier>
    {
    }
```

and in the view using

```
    <label for="SupplierName" class='details-label'>Supplier Name:</label>
    <span class='details-data'> <%= ViewData.Model.Name %> </span>
```

Comment: You can do directly Model.Name instead of ViewData.Model.Name, since Model is also a property of ViewPage<T>