# Pass a model to an MVCMailer view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I have a controller, which passes a model (ovw.ToList()) to a view:

```
    //
    // GET: /Clinic/Overview/
    public ActionResult Overview()
    {
        IEnumerable<Clinic> ovw = from c in db.Clinics
                                  select c;
        return View(ovw.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ttp.Models.Clinic>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
<div>@item.ClinicName</div>

   @foreach (var item2 in item.Properties)
         {
         <div>@item2.Address</div>
```

This works absolutely fine on screen.

When using MVCMailer, however , if I want to display the same layout in the email, how do I pass the ovw.ToList() to the mailer view, so that I can reference the same model in this way:

(I'm stuck on what to put in as the first line in the view):

```
@model IEnumerable<ttp.Models.Clinic>
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: hi can you please tell first you wont  to show all data in your index view

Answer (score 2):

You should find your answer in the 'Pass Data to Mailer Views' part of this guide: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

To pass your model along with the view to MVCMailer, you need to use ViewData:

```
var comment = new Comment {From = me, To = you, Message = "Great Work!"};
ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(comment);
```

Comment: Hi @kevin-d - thank you - I should have said, I have read the guide there - but what do I change @ foreach (var item in Model) to, to read/loop through the ViewData?  Thank you, Mark

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452567/how-do-i-access-viewdata-properties-in-my-view)
Use ViewData.Model instead of Model.

Answer (score -1):

In my project i doing like this it's below

i am showing all my category list in my index view

in my model class

```
public List<CategoryDetails> CategoryData { get; set; }
```

and i am also create CategoryDetails class and create a property to all my field 
like this

```
public int CatID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Category Name")]
public string CatName { get; set; }
public string CatImage { get; set; }
```

and create a function in my main model class like this

```
public void LoadCategory()
        {
            CategoryData = (from con in dbData.Categorys
                            select new CategoryDetails()
                            {
                                CatID = con.CatID,
                                CatName = con.CatName,
                                CatImage = con.CatImage,
                            }).ToList();
        }
```

In my controller i create a action like this

create my model class object and pass my model function to action

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           CategoryModel categorymodel = new CategoryModel();
            categorymodel.LoadCategory();
            return View(categorymodel);
        }
```

and in my view

```
@model PMS.Models.CategoryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Category Name
        </th>           
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryData)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CatName)
            </td>                             

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

i think this will help you

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVCMailer

Comment: This has nothing to do with the subject